# enable ESXi SDK WebService

Tags: vmware-esxi

On a freshly installed VMWare ESXi 4.1 I can't access `https://my_server/sdk/webService`, it gives me HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found.

I failed to find any docs about whether I needed to do any specific tasks to enable ESXi WebService API.

Could someone please direct me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Ok, it appeared that to test WebService API I had to ping `https://my_server/sdk/vim.wsdl`